# How to configure webpack in storybook to allow babel to import react components outside of project folder

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jsx, storybook

I am able to run storybook and develop react components within the storybook project folder successfully. However, I am trying to move the folder that contains all my components up a level (to be a sibling of the storybook folder).

So that instead of a structure like this

```
storybook
├── components
│   ├── Foo.js
│   └── Bar.js
├── stories
│   ├── index.stories.js
```

I have a folder structure like this

```
my_example_project
├── my_components
│   ├── Foo.js
│   └── Bar.js
├── my_storybook
│   ├── ...
```

When I try to import a component into a story, however, I get the following error

```
ERROR in ../my_components/Bar.js 4:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| const Bar = () => {
>   return <div>I am a Bar</div>;
| };
```

I've tried configuring my webpack to parse the components folder by adding a `webpack.config.js` file to my storybooks .storybook folder that looks like this

```js
const path = require('path');

// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {
  // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need

  config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: [/bower_components/, /node_modules/, /styles/],
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../my_components/*'),
      query: {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
  }
});


  // Return the altered config
  return config;
};
```

However, I run into the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a [github link](https://github.com/JeuelyFish/my_example_project) to the example of the full example project

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no.
I wanted this because I wanted to have another project directory use the components as a "shared-component" library.

My workaround was to keep the components folder inside storybook, and just alias a path from that project directory to the storybook folder... It's not ideal, and I would still love to learn what's going on

Comment: Sounds like we're trying to do similar things. I feel like there might be something with babel config that could associate everything properly but I'm having trouble figuring it out: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files/#project-wide-configuration

Answer (score 5):

I accomplished this by editing `.storybook/main.js` as following:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../src/**/*.stories.js',
    '../../../packages/react-components/src/**/*.stories.js'
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-docs',
    '@storybook/addon-viewport'
  ],

  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    // Ensure shared component stories are transpiled.
    config.module.rules[0].include.push(
      path.resolve('../../packages/react-components/src')
    );

    return config;
  }
};
```

Comment: In my case the config was much more complex. There is  a "oneOf" section in which I've found the rule with the babel-loader. But the general idea worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use this: https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/#debug-the-default-webpack-config

To debug the final webpack config. You'll likely have to change the include & exclude of the babel-loader.

By default it has `include: [ './' ]` in there, removing this should make it work, I think.

Answer (score 0):

In Storybook v6 the answer is a bit different

```
  // Inside storybook config
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    // Transpile local dependencies
    config.module.rules[5].oneOf[3].include.push(path.resolve(__dirname, 'YOUR_PATH'));

    return config;
  },
```

Of course, double-check if the rules index is correct for your case but that's the gist. Find the babel-loader config and add include path.