# How to dynamically import custom package with storybook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, storybook, ts-node

So I have a custom **private npm package** which I want to dynamically imports it like so.

```
export default function SelectedIcon({path, ...props}: Props) {
  const {data: icon} = require(`@mypackagelib/icons/${path}`)
  return <Icon icon={icon} {...props} />
}
// I also tried to have it differently such as: 
export default function SelectedIcon({path, ...props}: Props) {
  const Component = React.lazy(() => import(`@mypackagelib/icons/${path}`))
  return <Component {...props} />
}
// However, same error, so it seems like dynamically importing this is the problem
```

However, I got many errors, all the same message for different components in the library, from running Storybook

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:101)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| /// <reference types="react" />
| import { PropA, PropB } from '../../File';
> declare function NameOfAComponent(props: PropA): JSX.Element;
| declare namespace NameOfAComponent {
|     var data: PropB;
```

The weird thing that I don't understand is that, if I import the package like the below code, then it works

```
import OneOfTheComponent from '@mypackagelib/icons/OneOfTheComponent'
```

However, I have a case that I **need** to use dynamic import

I have the following config tsconfig.json when I build the **@mypackagelib** package with **tsc** and **ts-node**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "ES2020"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "pretty": false,
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "swc": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_moduls_local",
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "include": [
    "types.d.ts",
    "src/icons/**/*"
  ]
}
```

My `main.js` under ./storybook folder looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(ts|tsx)"
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
    {
      name: 'storybook-addon-swc', // I thought adding this will works, but it doesn't
      options: {
        enable: true,
        enableSwcLoader: true,
        enableSwcMinify: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
  experiments: {
    topLevelAwait: true,
  }
}
```

I think this might be webpack problem in general. What can I do to make it work? What loader do I need to add? What do my `main.js` file needs to look like? Why it needs a loader when I use dynamic imports but works fine if it's a normal import?

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring the babel-loader by adding a local package to the include paths. The answer on that topic is in a different question https://stackoverflow.com/a/75957498/2188869